# 3x3x3 Laplace Kernel?

Tags: differential-operators

Does anyone know what a 3x3x3 Laplacian kernel looks like? I realize that might be an open-ended question, but I need to apply a Laplacian convolution using a 3x3x3 Laplacian kernel, and frankly I don't know what it looks like...

**edit:** and by what it "looks like" I'm hoping someone can just tell me in the form of

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

4 4 4 
5 5 5 
6 6 6

7 7 7
8 8 8 
9 9 9
```

etc.

Comment: What's the context to this question? Since you specified 3x3x3, do you know the kernel for other dimensions? Laplace has made many contributions to mathematics, and kernel is a really overloaded word in mathematics, so a little bit of clarification may help jog our memories to help you.

Comment: Something tells me that the tag is inappropriate; although I must confess that I don't understand the question.

Comment: so I have an image I've applied a Gaussian blur too, which used a 3D kernel. I did not write the Gaussian kernel, but someone else did. Now I need to apply a Laplacian convolution to my image that was already convoluted with a Gaussian kernel. I found an example of a 2D Laplacian kernel (http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node8.html) but I can't figure out how to make a 3D kernel out of that.

Comment: this tag is definitely inappropriate, but i don't know which tag it belongs to and since I have low points, i couldn't add a simple and applicable tag like 'convolution' or 'laplace' because they don't exist. so i picked a random one.

Comment: In honour of J O'Rourke's answer, I am retagging this differential-operators.

Comment: While the answers you got are technically correct, I'd like to add that it's faster to do three one-dimensional Laplace convolutions, one in each direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (perhaps?) you are looking for the [discrete Laplacian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator). That Wikipedia page lists the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ convolution kernels explicitly.

Comment: +1 for the link to a page with an ADE classification I didn't know about!


Comment: you are my hero.

Comment: @Nick: Hardly heroic, but ... thanks! @José: I was also unaware of that ADE classification. An informative page!